How can I force data input into cells in Google Sheets to be in a desired date format?
I have a column of cells set to use a specific datetime format. However, when a user inputs something else, like 1 or 5/5 into one of the cells, it overrides the formatting setting and takes the input as-is.  In Excel, if I use that cell formatting and then input a 1, it changes it to 01/01/1900 00:00:00.  Is there a way to make Google Sheets do the same thing?
I can use data validation to make sure the input is a legitimate date, but it doesn't actually format it the way I need, it just gets rid of some really bad inputs, which aren't even my main concern.
I know there are regedit-based ways to get dates the way you need, but the ones I've seen require a separate input and result column, which doesn't work for our end-users just entering data in the one column.

It is a good question; I don't know if it can be achieved within Google Sheets.
You could use a script though: open 'Apps Script' in the 'Extensions' menu, and replace all the "myFunction" stuff with the following code:
function onEdit(e) {
  const columnLetter = "G";
  const colNum = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(`${columnLetter}1`).getColumn();
  const cell = e.range;
  if (cell.getColumn() === colNum) {
    cell.setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
}

You must modify two things:

replace the column letter (G in my example) with that of your specific column, leaving in the quotation marks - so "B";, not B; ;
replace the date-time format (the "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm" part) with your desired one. Here, I put a 25/09/2024 01:02 format, but you can custom that using the following guide: Date & number formats. Once again, leave the quotation marks.

That ought to do what you want: whenever a user edits any cell in the columnLetter column, the script will force the format.

Thank you, that is very helpful.  I'm actually a software developer so the AppScript thing isn't too daunting now that I see it but I've definitely never used it before.  No time like the present, I guess.
I'm honestly baffled that Sheets doesn't just do this.  Excel has worked this way for like 30 years!  Anyway, thanks again for your assistance.

I agree it does seem like a rather basic feature. You can always submit the idea to Google: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en. And don't worry, a couple of weeks ago I had never used Apps Script before either, but it's pretty straightforward. Anyway, if my answer helped you, don't hesitate to accept it and/or upvote it!  ^^

I've usually been more of a lurker on SO since many questions I've had were already asked and answered so I think this is only my second time actually interacting with it.  Thanks for the reminders about the accepting/upvote.  Apparently my work Google account I'm using here doesn't have the reputation required to officially vote yet but it said it logged my upvote feedback and I did accept it.  Thanks again.
